# Ajax framework from external file

Tags: ajax

I have created a custom module that use the ajaxcallbak in form 
and i call this module as block inside a external php in root installation

The external file contains the script for calling the bootstrap of Drupal and my custom module :

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);

define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());


//boostrap drupal
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);


$block = module_invoke('my_module', 'block_view', 'my_module');
print render($block['content']);
```

Inside my module i have :

```
function mymodule_init(){
     global $base_url;

    drupal_add_library('system', 'drupal.ajax');

    drupal_add_library('system', 'jquery.form');

}


function mymodule_form($form, &$form_state) {
  drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule');
  $form['myfield'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#size' => 25,
    '#default_value' => '',
    '#required' => false,
   );
    $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'button',
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'ajax_show_result',
      'name' => 'submit2',
      'effect' => 'fade',
      'event' => 'click',
    ),
    '#value' => t('Next'),
    '#attributes' => array('class' => array('btn_suite')),
    );
    return $form;
}


**
* Implementation du hook_block_info().
*/
function mymodule_block_info() {
  $blocks['mymodule'] = array(
    'info' => 'information',
    'cache' => DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_ROLE,
  );
  return $blocks;
}


/**
 * Implementation du hook_block_view().
 */
function mymodule_block_view($delta='') {
  $block = array();
  switch ($delta) {

  case 'mymodule':
      $block['subject'] = 'subject';
      $block['content'] = drupal_get_form('mymodule_form');
      break;

  }
  return $block;
}


function ajax_show_result($form, $form_state) { 
    $mydata= $form_state['values']['myfield'];
    echo $mydata;
}
```

what am i doing wrong? i'm not able to get the ajax callback firing , my form is always submitted

thanks

Comment: When i call this inside a template file of a page , this is working : $block = module_invoke('my_module', 'block_view', 'my_module');
print render($block['content']);   i think that there is something missing in my bootstrap call inside my external file to get it working but i do not know what :/

Comment: i'm get it working by integrate all my external in a new theme